# Question about spanning trees and creating them through BFS and/or DFS algorithms

Tags: algorithms, graphs, spanning-trees

The question is as follows:
True or False: For every non-directed connected non-weighted graph and for every spanning tree T of the graph there exists a vertex v such that T is a DFS tree with the root v.

What about if instead of DFS I used BFS?

I have no clue where to begin with this one. I feel like I'm overlooking some basic characteristic of the algorithm or the tree that it produces. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Please don't edit the content out of your question. If you've found the answer, you'll be able to write it up as an answer 8 hours after posting the question.

Answer (score 2):

If you get to pick, each time, an ordering of the vertices, then statement is trivially true - just choose the ordering that gives that tree, but this is not interesting.

Assuming the vertices do have some fixed order (so the DFS/BFS can't arbitrarily pick which vertex it has to choose next), then statement is false. We can see this via a simple counting argument. As the ordering is fixed, the DFS/BFS produces a unique spanning tree for each starting vertex, i.e. we can produce at most $n$ spanning trees (per algorithm), where $n$ is the number of vertices in the graph.

However if our input graph is $K_{n}$ with $n > 3$ (the complete graph on $n$ vertices), the graph has $n^{n-2}$ spanning trees, clearly far more than what we can produce from the DFS/BFS.